# How to create a discord avatar command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make an avatar command, but when I send the command, it does nothing with no error

**Discord Example Preview**: [discord preview img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3fwz.png)

Code:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'avt',
  description: "Used of user avatar",
  execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
    const avatarEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(0x333333)
        .setAuthor(user.username)
        .setImage(user.avatarURL);
    message.channel.send(avatarEmbed);
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you execute this command? This is usually in a file called index.js or message.js

Comment: @MrMythical
```javascript
 client.on('message', async message => {
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
  let command = args.shift().toLowerCase()
      if(command === "avt"){
        client.commands.get("avt").execute(message, args, Discord)
  }
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`User.avatarURL`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/User?scrollTo=avatarURL) is a function. You need to remember to put the `()`.

Change it from `user.avatarURL` to `user.avatarURL()`

```js
//...
.setImage(user.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
```

Comment: Its working but there is pb behind it . If user profile type is gif is not give me the gif picture

Comment: I edited it. It should work by adding `{dynamic: true}`